# bashrc file read error in xterm

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

My bashrc files is read but is not interpreted correctly.

```
qwul@qwul-ThinkPad-L440:~$ cat .bashrc
#PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\][\W]\$\[\[\e[0m\]\]\] '
alias la="ls -a"
#alias ll="ls -l"
qwul@qwul-ThinkPad-L440:~$ appres xterm
xterm*borderWidth:      0
xterm*font:     *-fixed-*-*-*-18-*
xterm*selectToClipboard:        true
*customization: -color
qwul@qwul-ThinkPad-L440:~$ la
's: invalid option -- '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

The PS1 setting if enabled, starts text from first column, overwriting prompt.

Copy pasting PS1 and alias works as expected from CLI.

Comment: which OS are you using ? I have no problem in ubuntu.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: your config should work, try to run `dos2unix .bashrc`

Comment: Answer your own question if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix .bashrc , as suggested by  Archemar worked.

From http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

> DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n"). You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are translated properly.